# Minificar batch

Tags: windows, batch

Existe algum tipo de comando batch ou software para minificar arquivos `.batch` ?

Assim como existe com minify para minificar arquivos `.js` ou `.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não, pois `.batch` são comandos executados sequencialmente, diferente do `.js` que é `multi-paradigma`, e o `.css` é interpretado pelo navegador, buscando arquivos já pré definidos.

Em resumo, o `.Batch` ou `.sh` não pode ser minificado.

Comment: Existe ao menos a possibilidade de encriptar o `batch` ?

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Uma possível solução está sendo explicada abaixo para **simular** um **script minificado**.

**Antes de tudo**, ressalto que os **estilos minificados** precisam ser utilizados **apenas em casos específicos**, pois é uma prática que retira o **código limpo (clear code)**, dificultando a manutenção.

Outro fator importante a ser considerado é que devemos entender o **propósito de minificar um código** e **como pode ser aplicado para cada linguagem de programação**, pois isso se torna diferente devido à **próprias regras de sintaxe da linguagem** e de seu **respectivo interpretador e/ou compilador**.

O **propósito do estilo minificado** tem o seguinte **conceito**:

> o **objetivo do estilo minificado** é **garantir ganhos de
> desempenho/performance** e/ou **remover dados/caracteres desnecessários** para a
> **execução do código**, esses dados mudam conforme a linguagem de
> programação que está sendo utilizada - o que de fato pode incluir **a
> remoção de tabulações, comentários, espaços, quebra de linhas, etc**.

A alternativa mais plausível e direta para **chegar próximo** aos estilos *minificados* nos **scripts batch**, será a utilização dos operadores:

> `&` representa `E`,  `|` representa `OU`, `&&` representa `SUCESSO NA OPERAÇÃO`, `||` representa `FALHA NA OPERAÇÃO`.

Dessa maneira um código batch de **N linhas** pode ser executado em apenas **1 linha** ou terá **menos linhas** do que sua **versão original**. Casos onde é necessário utilizar rótulos de repetição não poderão ser aplicados ao estilo minificado.

Abaixo estão exemplos de execução semelhantes à estilo minificado.

Você pode **optar executando o cmd.exe** com **o parâmetro /c** para rodar a sequência de comandos do script desejado:

```
cmd /e /v /c "for /l %a in (0,1,10) do (cls & echo %a & echo. & set /p num=Qual numero voce viu? & if %a==!num! (echo Ok. & pause>nul) else (echo Errado.) & pause>nul)"
```

O **mesmo script dentro do arquivo .bat** pode ser escrito da **seguinte forma**:

```
@echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & for /l %%a in (0,1,10) do (cls & echo %%a & echo. & set /p num=Qual numero voce viu? & if %%a==!num! (echo Ok. & pause>nul) else (echo Errado.) & pause>nul)
```

Em sua **versão original**, aplicando **conceitos de código limpo**, e no padrão da linguagem está assim:

```
@ECHO off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    
:: Exibição de números de 0 à 10 
:: O usuário deve acertar o número que apareceu.
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 10) do (
   cls
   echo %%a
   echo.
   cls
   set /p num=Qual numero voce viu?
   if %%a==!num! (
      echo Ok.
      pause >nul
   ) else (
      echo Errado.
      pause>nul
   )
)

Exit
```